# razor pages url in area with prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

So i was looking a lot on several topics here and learningrazorpages. but i cannot figure something out.

so on my setup i have area

```
Identity
    /pages
    /account
    /login
```

```cs
services
    .AddMvc(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.UseCentralRoutePrefix(new RouteAttribute(path));
    })
```

on my controllers this works like a charm. But it looks like on my razor pages this is not honored.

so now i have to write this in my *.cshtml.

```
@page "~/PREFIX/identity/account/login2"
```

but i dont want to write this on all my pages.
can i do this easy with razor conventions on an area?

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {...}); ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor Pages routing is configured via [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and is not affected by the [application model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that is used in MVC. In order to apply a custom convention that affects all pages in an area, you can target the area and root folder with something like the following:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
    {
        o.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/", pageRouteModel =>
        {
            foreach (var selectorModel in pageRouteModel.Selectors)
                selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template = "PREFIX/" + selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
        });
    });
```

This example configures a convention for the root (using `/`) of the `Identity` area, which iterates over all of the existing templates and adds `PREFIX/` to each.